# How to burn a Linux distro ISO image from Linux Live?

Tags: linux-mint, live-usb, iso

Mint screwed my grub (no more dual boot with Win7) because of a faulty LIVE USB flash stick.
(I can launch Mint but I can't install)

I need to burn a new ISO to my USB flash stick or USB drive so that I can properly install Linux and restore the grub.

I tried to use Xfburn and USB Image Writer which are default in Mint X but both applications don't detect the USB stick or the USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you can boot any linux on the machine, follow instructions in [Fixing Lilo with uefi system and no optical drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78740/fixing-lilo-with-uefi-system-and-no-optical-drive/78955#78955) (obviously you'll need to adjust it for different bootloader).

To transfer the image to a Flash USB drive directly, you can use `dd`:

```
dd if=/path/to/your.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=8M
```

where `/dev/sdX` is the kernel device of your USB drive. This of course destroys any data*) previously on the USB (but any method does that anyway). As a side note, the verb "burn" is usually used only when the target media is written to with a laser (e.g. all the variants of CD/DVD/BD), which flash is not.

See also this [guide on Fedoraproject](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB#Simple_command_line_method:_write_the_image_directly).

*) strictly speaking, in the case of a flash memory based device it doesn't really neither *destroy* nor *all* the data - due to wear leveling, the blocks are realocated, so some of the previous content will stay untouched and also only the beginning of the device will be erased (writing 3GB image on 8GB flash doesn't alter the last 5GB).

Answer (score 0):

I generally use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for burning distros to USB devices. Depending how you want to install, it can either use an already downloaded ISO or it will download and install an ISO of your choosing for a variety of distros.

[image: ss of unetbootin]

Answer (score 0):

To write an ISO image to a USB stick you can do the following after unmounting the stick:

```
cp /path/to/image.iso /dev/sdX
sync
```